# Swift Complex type in parameter

Tags: swift, type-alias

In order to be a bit more clear I am looking for a solution for the user to pass a class with a specific subclass and protocol, i.e. a class that inherits a viewController and delegate protocol. I know its possible to create a protocol list but cannot find a solution that works correctly. Currently I use a  initializer and use the viewcontroller as a parameter and check for delegate inside the function but I would rather if I can have these types in the parameter instead.

EDIT:
Looking to do something similar to this

```
Protocol prot:Delegate{}

class cla:ViewController{}

class impl{
      init(mainUI: cla, prot){
         do things
       }
}

That way back in the main view controller I can do something like this

class viewController: cla, prot{

     var view:impl  

     override func loadView() {
        //Attach to Screen
        view = impl(mainUI: self);
    }

}
```

Their is a bit more happening but that's the only part thats really relevant. Currently I use a  initializer to just fail if the class doesn't inherit the correct protocols

Comment: Your question is extremely vague without some code. Please edit it and include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dummy type that represents your requirements. A typealias doesn't work in this case, but this might:

```
class DummyClass: MyViewController, MyDelegateProtocol {}

func needsRequiredClass(input: DummyClass) {...}
```

With `MyViewController` and `MyDelegateProtocol` being the superclass and delegate you mentioned. The `DummyClass` would have an empty implementation.

Then, make your specific classes sub classes of `DummyClass`:

```
class TestClass: DummyClass {...}
```

And you can pass in that new class:

```
let test = TestClass()
self.needsRequiredClass(test)
```

Comment: This is a better solution based off of BaseZen's response. This is what I would do in other languages but I wanted to see if swift had an interesting way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the wrong question. In other words trying to shoe-horn in a serious design mistake.

A view should *not* know that its delegate is a UIViewController or a subclass.

A delegate should be *any* class that obeys (adopts) a specific delegate protocol.

A view should only delegate specific responsibilities. Each of those responsibilities *must* be described by a protocol method or property.

If you explain what your issue is in more detail (why you think you need direct access to the entire definition of a `UIViewController` within a `UIView`), we can help you avoid this mistake.

Comment: Re-did based on your description

Comment: Yes I see it is better to simply create a superclass that inherits what I need and require the user to call that instead. @Pops solution is probably what I would do in other languages but after seeing a lot of what swift can do I wondered if it had an interesting solution